# How to update a specific driver?

Tags: wireless, drivers

How can i update this rtl8192cu driver to the latest version?

```
sudo lshw -C network
    *-network

         description: Ethernet interface
         product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
         vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
         physical id: 0
         bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
         logical name: enp3s0
         version: 06
         serial: 94:de:80:da:86:dc
         size: 10Mbit/s
         capacity: 1Gbit/s
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
         configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
         resources: irq:26 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f0804000-f0804fff memory:f0800000-f0803fff
    *-network
         description: Wireless interface
         physical id: 1
         bus info: usb@1:5
         logical name: wlxc04a002465d6
         serial: c0:4a:00:24:65:d6
         capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
         configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192cu ip=192.168.1.3 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a better driver suite for your device. I suggest that you do, in a terminal and with a solid connection:
Code:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8192cu.git
sudo dkms add ./rtl8192cu
sudo dkms install rtl8192cu/0.1
```

Reboot.