# installing wireless drivers offline for ubuntu 15.10

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, offline

I have installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 8.1. But the wifi is not working in ubuntu.
This post that i asked before some days [How to update a specific driver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/741674/how-to-update-a-specific-driver/741786#741786) works for me but i am formating all the time(kernel was the last reason) and its not easy for me to move the PC from one room to another . Is there any way for me to install the wifi in offline?.

```
*-network
 description: Ethernet interface
 product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
 vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
 physical id: 0
 bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
 logical name: enp3s0
 version: 06
 serial: 94:de:80:da:86:dc
 size: 10Mbit/s
 capacity: 1Gbit/s
 width: 64 bits
 clock: 33MHz
 capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
 configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
 resources: irq:26 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f0804000-f0804fff memory:f0800000-f0803fff
```

*-network
     description: Wireless interface
     physical id: 1
     bus info: usb@1:5
     logical name: wlxc04a002465d6
     serial: c0:4a:00:24:65:d6
     capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
     configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192cu ip=192.168.1.3 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn

Comment: Why do are you asking about Broadcom drivers? Do you have a Broadcom device?

Comment: You format for a kernel?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you back up the rtl891cu file that you obtained from the other thread you linked to a USB key or similar. Also, download the *dkms* package that you can find here: http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dkms/dkms_2.2.0.3-2ubuntu6_all.deb Copy that to the USB key also.

If you need to re-install or reformat, after the installation, drag and drop both files to your desktop. Then open a terminal and do:

```
cd ~/Desktop
```

"Desktop" may be named something else if your installation is not English; if so, substitute for "Desktop" here. For example:

```
cd ~/Escritorio
```

Then do:

```
sudo dpkg -i dkms*.deb
sudo dkms add ./rtl8192cu
sudo dkms install rtl8192cu/0.1
```